# Как закрыть AlertDialog с помощью кнопки в его разметке?

Tags: java, android

Создаю AlertDialog:

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    adb.setTitle(R.string.dlg_fonts);
    view = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
    adb.setView(view);
    tvDlg = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDlg);
    etDlg = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etDlg);
    btnDlgOk = (Button)  view.findViewById(R.id.btnDlgOk);
    btnDlgCancel = (Button)  view.findViewById(R.id.btnDlgCancel);
    return adb.create();
}
@Override
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
    super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog);

}
// В разметке есть событие на кнопку onClick
public void onclDlgOk(View view){
}
```

Как сделать, чтобы после нажатия на кнопку диалоговое окно закрылось?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    adb.setTitle(R.string.dlg_fonts);
    view = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
    adb.setView(view);
    tvDlg = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDlg);
    etDlg = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etDlg);
    btnDlgOk = (Button)  view.findViewById(R.id.btnDlgOk);
    btnDlgCancel = (Button)  view.findViewById(R.id.btnDlgCancel);

    Dialog dialog = adb.create();

    btnDlgCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){public void onClick(View v){dialog.dismiss();}});

    return dialog ;
}
```

Comment: Ругается на строку "new View.OnClickListener()", кажется хочет создать отдельно OnClick(). Написанный (public void onClick(){dialog.dismiss();}}) выделен серым цветом, т.е. не задействует его.

Comment: @kaaa, попробуйте самостоятельно набрать, может я опечатался где-то. Т.е. набрать `new On` и `Ctrl+Space`

Comment: требует прописать id в dialog.dismiss(); прописал(dismissDialog(id)), но при нажатии приложение "вылетает".

Comment: Заработало! Благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример другого диалога:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                alt_bld.setTitle(R.string.my_title)
                        .setItems(R.array.my_array, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog_one, int position) {

                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(R.string.action_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int position) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert = alt_bld.create();
                alert.setIcon(R.drawable.my_icon);
                alert.show();
```

Comment: В этом примере нет разметки (или я не вижу). А мне надо с использованием разметки в xml.